# Center of the Orthogonal Group and Special Orthogonal Group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, orthogonal-matrices

How can I prove that the center of $\operatorname{O}_n$ is $\pm I_n$?

I have that $AM = MA$, $\forall M \in \operatorname{O}_n$ and $A^{-1} = A^T$, $M^{-1} = M^T$.

Then $M = A^{-1}MA = A^{T}MA$.

I see that since conjugating by $A$ must leave the determinant of $M$ unchanged then the result of conjugation must be a rotation. But now I'm stuck.

How to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is false for $n=2$.  So solving the problem for $n \ge 3$ must involve getting your hands dirty and looking at the structure of the matrix.

Comment: It's false for $SO_2$ but not for $O_2$. I proved it below for O_n without restriction on $n$.

Comment: I'm glad my mistake helped.

Comment: You were right there's no getting around some hand dirtying.  I found a proof for $SO_n$ as well, by a similar method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hints:

1. By considering $AD=DA$ for some diagonal matrices $D$ with diagonal entries in $\{-1,1\}$, show that $A$ is a diagonal matrix.
2. By considering $AR=RA$ for some [Givens rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) $R$, show that all diagonal entries of $A$ are equal to each other.

Answer (score 17):

Alright, I answered my own question:

Suppose $A$ commutes with every element in $O_n$.

Then $A$ must commute with the elementary orthogonal matrices.

These are

1. the identity
2. the row switching/column switching matrices
3. the matrices that are identical to the identity but with a -1 for one of the entries on the main diagonal.

Then $AE = EA$ implies  $A = EAE^{-1}$.

Now, conjugation by Type 2 matrices shows that all the elements on the diagonal must be equal.

And conjugation by Type 3 matrices shows that all the off-diagonal elements must be zero.  Suppose we have that the $a_{ii}$ entry of Type 3 is -1 then conjugation leaves $a_{ii}$ unchanged but reverses the signs of all the elements in the same row and column as $a_{ii}$.

Since $A$ must also have determinant $\pm 1$, then the only matrices in the center must be $\pm I$.

The center of $SO_n$ is $\{ \pm I \}$ for $n > 3$ and $SO_2$ for $n=2$.

Suppose A commutes with every element in $SO_n$. Then $A$ must commute with the following matrices,

1. a row switching transformation where one of the switched rows is multiplied by -1.
2. a double row multiplying transformation where the multiplier is -1 in each case.

Now conjugation by Type I, shows that all the elements on the main diagonal must be equal, and that $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$ for $i \neq j$.

And conjugation by Type 2 matrices shows that for $n > 2$ all the non-main-diagonal elements must be zero.

Since A must also have determinant $1$, then the only matrices in the center must be

1. $SO_2$ if $n=2$. (All matrices in $SO_2$ meet the first condition.
   This is easily verified by taking arbitrary matrices in $SO_2$ and using sum of angle identities.)
2. $I$ if $n$ is odd.
3. $\pm I$ if $n$ is even.