# What is the center of SO(p,q)?

Tags: lie-groups

For the matrix lie group $SO(p,q)$, what is in the center? Is there anything other than $I_n$ (or $-I_n$ in the case $p+q=n$ is even)?

Also where can I find a reference?

Comment: I could not find anything about the center on that wikipedia article.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say that I didnt find anything about the center of SO(p,q) on that page.

Comment: This link [here](http://catalog.lib.kyushu-u.ac.jp/en/recordID/1001254439) might be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center of the Orthogonal Group and Special Orthogonal Group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554957/center-of-the-orthogonal-group-and-special-orthogonal-group)

Comment: @hjhjhj57 the question you linked does not contain an answer to this question. This is the special orthogonal group of a nondegenerate bilinear form that is not necessarily positive definite.

Comment: @MattSamuel wouldn't the second answer work with some little changes?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 I don't know enough about the structure of the group to answer that question, but if you see a way to make it work this case perhaps you should answer the question. It's not close enough to qualify as a duplicate in my opinion.

Comment: Keep in mind that $\text{SO}(2) \cong S^1$ and $\text{SO}(1, 1) \cong \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ are both abelian, so in these cases the center is the whole thing.

Comment: While reading Shlomo Sternberg's third section of "On charge conjugation" I came across the affirmation that $$ \begin{pmatrix}\pm I_{p\times p} & 0 \\ 0 & \pm I_{q\times q} \end{pmatrix}$$ is the center of $O(p,q)$. Of course this isn't a proof, but it may be useful. Let me know if you want the complete reference.

Comment: Thanks hjhjhj577. This answers my question. However, the Sternberg paper doesn't have an explanation nor a reference to why it is the case.